# How to execute mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test?

Tags: java, spring, maven, mybatis, spring-mybatis

For [mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/tree/master/mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test) I see no main method and even no Java file. It has two dependencies of which [mybatis-spring-boot-test-autoconfigure](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/tree/master/mybatis-spring-boot-test-autoconfigure) contains some test files and I can execute them while [spring-boot-starter-test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-test) just has a pom file.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So how can I execute these test modules? It I can't, it's created for what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module is not for "execution". Take a look at [their docs](http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/):

> ## What is MyBatis-Spring-Boot-Starter-Test?
>
> The MyBatis-Spring-Boot-Starter-Test help creating a test cases for MyBatis component using the [MyBatis-Spring-Boot-Starter](http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/).
>
> By using this module you will can be:
>
> - Can use the `@MybatisTest` that setup test components for testing pure MyBatis component
> - Can import dependency artifacts for performing tests for pure MyBatis component

So, this module [provides](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/blob/master/mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.provides) you [`@MybatisTest`](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/blob/master/mybatis-spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/mybatis/spring/boot/test/autoconfigure/MybatisTest.java) from [`mybatis-spring-boot-test-autoconfigure`](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/tree/master/mybatis-spring-boot-test-autoconfigure). That's, basically, what "starters" are: a group of (possibly one, like in this case) dependencies that are intended to work together to provide some features.

[Read more](http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/#Using_MybatisTest) about using @MybatisTest.

Comment: Looks like the link is boken